# PowerShell which - get usable path

Tags: powershell, path

EDIT: I'm on Windows 10 and I think the `which` command is available because of an installation of Git for Windows.

If I type `which nvm` in to PowerShell, I get `/c/Users/HP/AppData/Roaming/nvm/nvm`. If I then want to navigate to that location, `/cd c/Users/HP/AppData/Roaming/nvm/nvm` fails as path not found.

How can I get a path that I can use with `cd` please?

Comment: the command `which nvm` does not work on my end. Anything I need to install? The path you get is a linux path. Are you on windows? does which offer the ability to return a windows path instead?

Comment: Is that a typo or are you missing the leading `/` in `cd c/users...`?

Comment: [1] `which` is not a standard windows command. [2] `which` is not a powershell command. [3] `c/users` is NOT valid on windows. you need at least the `:` that goes after the drive letter. something like `c:/users`.

Comment: the equivalent command for windows is `where.exe` ... but you MUST use the full command with the `.exe` when in powershell since it will otherwise call `Where-Object`.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using PowerShell anyway, why not using PowerShell?

The equivalent of `which` or `where.exe` in PowerShell is `Get-Command`. This will return an object. Example:

```
Get-Command ping
```

Output:

```
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     PING.EXE                                           10.0.18... C:\Windows\system32\PING.EXE
```

As you are looking for the path, you need the `Path` property:

```
(Get-Command ping).Path
```

Output:

```
C:\Windows\system32\PING.EXE
```

This is at least a path, Windows will understand. But you cannot change your working directory to it as it is not a directory, but an executable. You can again use some PowerShell magic and extract the parent path of the executable:

```
Split-Path (Get-Command ping).Path
```

Output:

```
C:\Windows\system32
```

You can then use this path to change your working directory. Btw, `cd` in PowerShell is an alias for `Set-Location` which you can verify with `Get-Command cd`. In conclusion you can pipe your result to `cd` or to `Set-Location` and get your desired solution in one line (prompt not stripped to see the result):

```
PS C:\> Split-Path (Get-Command ping).Path | cd
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: +1 But `Split-Path (Get-Command ping).Source` didn't work for me. However, looking at the [official documentation for Get-Command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command?view=powershell-7), using `Definition` in place of `Source` did (so `Split-Path (Get-Command ping).Definition`).

Comment: @Anaksunaman Thanks for the hint. I checked the docs: I think it would even better to use the `Path` property. Does that work on your machine? Which OS and PS version are you using btw.?

Comment: *"Does that work on your machine? "* - Yes. `Split-Path (Get-Command ping).Path` does the job. =) For reference, test machine is running Windows 7 with PowerShell 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

> I think the `which` command is available because of an installation of Git for Windows.

As alluded to in the comments, Git for Windows does not use the same path format as PowerShell (or Windows broadly). The `which` command you are using is apparently returning a path meant to be used in ex. Git Bash.

Of particular note:

- PowerShell and Windows do not typically use forward slashes (`/`) as path separators. Instead, backwards slashes `\` are used natively.
- Drive letter are not specified as `/drive/`. They are specified as `drive:\`.

Bearing this in mind, the equivalent path to:

```
/c/Users/HP/AppData/Roaming/nvm/nvm
```

in PowerShell is:

```
c:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\nvm\nvm.ext
```

Note that `ext.` in this case is just meant at a generic extension (likely `.exe`). Also, `/cd` is likely not valid and the last `nvm` is likely the executable itself (minus an extension i.e. whatever `ext` might be).  So you can just use i.e.:

```
cd c:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\nvm
```

> How can I get a path that I can use with `cd` please?

As noted several times elsewhere, `where` in `cmd` (a normal command window) and `where.exe` (in PowerShell) will return a correctly formatted path for Windows such as e.g. `c:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\nvm\nvm.ext` above (so either `where nvm` in `cmd` or `where.exe nvm` in PowerShell). Just drop the final executable name.